# Kafka broker.id: env variable vs config file precedence

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm setting up a Kafka cluster, in which I'm setting the `broker.id=-1` so that `broker.id`s are automatically generated. but in some cases want to set them using environment variables (i.e. `KAFKA_BROKER_ID`).

If done so, will the nodes with the `KAFKA_BROKER_ID` env variables use the env variable or auto-generate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you are deploying your Kafka installation.

Out of the box, Kafka does not use system properties to configure broker id, so you need to put the value into `.properties` file.
(among others: grepping for KAFKA_BROKER_ID in Kafka source returns nothing)

`KAFKA_BROKER_ID` appears to be added by multiple Docker images, you'd need to contact the author of the one you are using.

Comment: Thanks.
turns out said environment variable is used in [this file](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.2.1-post/debian/kafka/include/etc/confluent/docker/kafka.properties.template) by Confluent's Kafka Docker image.